# Dynamic Nested Loops Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

This is the array I require:

```
N = 6
A = [[x,y,z] for x in range(N+1) for y in range(N+1) for z in range(N+1) if x+y+z== N]
```

Is there any other way of doing this by only specifying the variable `N` and `3` instead of x,y,z?
I tried `[]*3` but can't get the required output.

Comment: Hint: once you have x and y, you know what z has to be.

Comment: You can use `itertools.product`, but you will have to filter afterwards (like you do now, without above trick), meaning you get generate and discard a lot of junk. Complexity will be `N^K`

Comment: Does the code you've shown work correctly and you are just trying to simplify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`iterttols.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```py
from itertools import product

N = 6
A = [(x,y,z) for x in range(N+1) for y in range(N+1) for z in range(N+1) if x+y+z== N]
B = [tup for tup in product(range(N+1), repeat=3) if sum(tup) == N]
print(A, B, A == B, sep='\n')
```

Gives:

```
[(0, 0, 6), (0, 1, 5), (0, 2, 4), (0, 3, 3), (0, 4, 2), (0, 5, 1), (0, 6, 0), (1, 0, 5), (1, 1, 4), (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (1, 4, 1), (1, 5, 0), (2, 0, 4), (2, 1, 3), (2, 2, 2), (2, 3, 1), (2, 4, 0), (3, 0, 3), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1), (3, 3, 0), (4, 0, 2), (4, 1, 1), (4, 2, 0), (5, 0, 1), (5, 1, 0), (6, 0, 0)]
[(0, 0, 6), (0, 1, 5), (0, 2, 4), (0, 3, 3), (0, 4, 2), (0, 5, 1), (0, 6, 0), (1, 0, 5), (1, 1, 4), (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (1, 4, 1), (1, 5, 0), (2, 0, 4), (2, 1, 3), (2, 2, 2), (2, 3, 1), (2, 4, 0), (3, 0, 3), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1), (3, 3, 0), (4, 0, 2), (4, 1, 1), (4, 2, 0), (5, 0, 1), (5, 1, 0), (6, 0, 0)]
True
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`itertools.combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement):

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
n = 6
k = 3

# If you want a list of tuples:
lst = [item for item in list(combinations_with_replacement(range(n), k)) if sum(item) == n]
print(lst)
# [(0, 1, 5), (0, 2, 4), (0, 3, 3), (1, 1, 4), (1, 2, 3), (2, 2, 2)]

# If you want a list of lists:
lst = [list(item) for item in list(combinations_with_replacement(range(n), k)) if sum(item) == n]
print(lst)
# [[0, 1, 5], [0, 2, 4], [0, 3, 3], [1, 1, 4], [1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, but what I needed was permutations, and has been given a valid answer by @Tomerikoo.